# tensorflow, how to join the tf.string SparseTensor to 1-D dense tensor

Tags: string, tensorflow

tensorflow has tf.string_split function that can split dense tensor to SparseTensor, but not provided the opposite function.

anyone knows how to do it? thanks~

for example:
SparseTensor:

```
[["a", "b", "c"]
 ["d", "e"]
 ["f", "g", "h", "i"]]
```

join SparseTensor with separator " " to dense tensor:

```
["a b c",
 "d e",
 "f g h i"]
```

tensorflow中SparseTensor格式：

```
# indices = tf.constant([[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 0], [1, 1], [2, 0], [2, 1], [2, 2], [2, 3]], dtype=tf.int64)
# values = tf.constant(["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i"], dtype=tf.string)
# dense_shape = tf.constant([3, 4], dtype=tf.int64)
# tf.SparseTensor(indices=indices, values=values, dense_shape=dense_shape)
```

update question:

```
join_words_list = []
slice_words_list = tf.sparse_split(sp_input=sparse_words, num_split=3, axis=0)
# slice_words_list = tf.sparse_split(sp_input=sparse_words, num_split=sparse_words.dense_shape[0], axis=0)
for slice_words in slice_words_list:
  slice_words = slice_words.values
  join_words = tf.reduce_join(slice_words, reduction_indices=0, separator=" ")
  join_words_list.append(join_words)
join_str = tf.stack(join_words_list)
```

now, this create the new problem, [tensorflow, split tf.string SparseTensor to the list of dense Tensor in dim 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43250908/tensorflow-split-tf-string-sparsetensor-to-the-list-of-dense-tensor-in-dim-0)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `sparse_string_join` implementation that does what you are looking for:

```
def sparse_string_join(input_sp):
  """Concats each row of SparseTensor `input_sp` and outputs them as a 1-D string tensor."""

  # convert the `SparseTensor` to a dense `Tensor`
  dense_input = tf.sparse_to_dense(input_sp.indices, input_sp.dense_shape, input_sp.values, default_value='')

  # concat each row of strings.
  strings = tf.reduce_join(dense_input, axis=1, separator=' ')

  # remove extra spaces.  
  return tf.string_strip(strings)
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [string_join](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/string_join)

```
output = tf.string_join([input0, input1])
```

Comment: tf.string_join will join the dense tensor, but failed to SparseTensor

Comment: Does doing `tf.sparse_to_dense` before `tf.string_join` work?