# tensorflow, split tf.string SparseTensor to the list of dense Tensor in dim 0

Tags: split, tensorflow

Anyone knows how to split tf.string SparseTensor to the list of dense Tensor in dim 0, like this:

sparse_input -> slice_input_list

SparseTensor :

```
[["a", "b", "c"],
 ["d", "e"],
 ["f", "g", "h", "i"]]

# raw_dense_input = tf.constant(["a b c", "d e", "f g h i"], dtype=tf.string)
# sparse_input = tf.string_split(raw_dense_input)
```

To : dense Tensor list:

```
list(["a", "b", "c"], ["d", "e"], ["f", "g", "h", "i"])

# slice_input_list = (tf.constant(["a", "b", "c"], dtype=tf.string), 
# tf.constant(["d", "e"], dtype=tf.string), 
# tf.constant(["f", "g", "h", "i"], dtype=tf.string))
```

I tried to using the following method, but failed, because that num_split need int, and dense_shape is dynamic shape

```
slice_input_list = tf.sparse_split(sp_input=sparse_input, num_split=sparse_input.dense_shape[0], axis=0)
```